# Update Location after every 2 minutes on server android

Tags: java, android, service, background, alarmmanager

Method to upload location to server every 2 minutes. 
I am currently using Alarm Manager currently and some operating system close the Alarm Manager and the alarm donot ring after a particular interval of time. What is some other solutions that I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Please read this article:
https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling.html#am

> The AlarmManager API is another option that the framework provides for scheduling tasks. This API is useful in cases in which an app needs to post a notification or set off an alarm at a very specific time.

**Location Manager** - Android system offers location changes in runtime through location manager. Repeating updates can be achieved by using [LocationManager#requestLocationUpdates](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String,%20long,%20float,%20android.location.LocationListener))

Comment: can Location Manager be used when the app is killed by the user. I need to update the location after every 2 minutes even if the app is in foreground, background or killed state

Comment: You can receive packages from Location Manager only when you are in your app, because you have to register.

But read this one (right over Background Services Limitations): https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background.html#overview